# Magento 2 How to include custom library in controller

Tags: api, magento2.3, controllers, third-party-library, call

I have created custom extension with some library classes. I have placed the libraries in lib/internal/SSOSdk folder. I need to include one of the library class in my controller. I have used the below code but it gives Class not found error.

Here is my code

```
namespace Company\Sso\Controller\Login;

require_once('lib/internal/SSOSdk/SSO.php');


    class Login extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
        private $resultPageFactory;

        private $scopeConfig;

        public $storeManager;    

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
        ) {
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
            $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }

         public function execute()
        {
            $apiUrl = 'test.com';
            $clientId = '123';
            $clientSecret = '456';

            $params = $_GET;

            $sso = new SSO($apiUrl, $clientId, $clientSecret);
            try {
                if($params['error']){
                    $sso->notifyJs(false, $params);
                }else{               
                    $sso->notifyJs(true, $params);                
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $sso->notifyJs(false, $e);
            }


        }
    }
```

SSO.php

```
class SSO {

    private $_clientId, $_clientSecret, $_hostUrl;


    public function __construct($hostUrl, $clientId, $clientSecret){
        $this->_hostUrl = $hostUrl;
        $this->_clientId = $clientId;
        $this->_clientSecret =$clientSecret;
    }


    public function setHostUrl($hostUrl){
        $this->_hostUrl = $hostUrl;
    }
    .......

}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: is `SSO.php` has any class name space?

Comment: @AmitBera No, I have added the SSO.php code

Comment: A single file right Or your have  multi-files on this API

Comment: @AmitBera Yes, I have multi-files

Comment: You have to convert your class to psr-2 format https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Comment: @AmitBera  I need to convert all these files?

Comment: try this `require_once(__DIR__ . '../../../../lib/internal/SSOSdk/SSO.php');` and use  `new \SSO`  instead `new SSO`

Comment: @AmitBera Thank you so much, Now it is working. Is this the right method to use?

Comment: I am not sure about this process is right for Magento. But conversion to pSR 2 standard  is the solution

Comment: Okay, I will do it.

Comment: wait. i don't think you need include. Please check only need  `new \SSO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

> ```
> require_once(__DIR__ . '../../../../lib/internal/SSOSdk/SSO.php');
> ```

**instead of**

> ```
> require_once('lib/internal/SSOSdk/SSO.php');
> ```

Also.use

> ```
> new \SSO
> ```

**instead of**

> ```
> new SSO
> ```

But I suggest converting your classes to `psr-2` format php-fig.org/psr/psr-2 right solution.

Comment: I have only changed the object creation section,ie, use  new \SSO 

instead of    new SSO